# c#, MSBuild Bootstrapper with wix, how to download .net framework 3.5 SP1?

Tags: c#, msbuild, wix, bootstrapping

I managed to create bootstrapper for my project that includes .net framework 3.5SP1 with this code:

```
  <ItemGroup>  
    <BootstrapperFile Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">  
        <Visible>False</Visible>  
        <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5.SP1</ProductName>  
        <Install>true</Install>  
      </BootstrapperFile>        
    </ItemGroup>  
    <Target Name="Bootstrapper">  
      <GenerateBootstrapper  
        ApplicationFile="SeppelSetup.msi"  
        ApplicationName="Seppel 1.0"  
        BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)"  
        OutputPath=".\bin\Debug"  
        ComponentsLocation="Relative"  
        Culture="en"  
        Path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper"  
      />  
    </Target>
```

The problem is that output directory has over 200Mb, wich is much more than I can afford (I want to put installer online for download). Is there a way that allow me to download framework from microsoft's site rather than include all files in installation package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Bootstrapper element Remove your ComponentsLocation="Relative" attribute
and add following

ComponentsLocation="Homesite"

CopyComponents="true"

Comment: it should be ComponentsLocation="HomeSite" , note the S should be in upper case.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is probably to use [Wix 3.6](http://wix.sourceforge.net/downloadv36.html). It was nowhere near complete the last time I tried it, but it supports exactly the sort of thing you want, downloading redistributables from the Internet. If you're willing to wait for it to be stable, go with it.